# does Oracle 11g has some tools to track the SQL Statement sending to Oracle?

Tags: oracle

It's Oracle 11g in windows 2016.

Does Oracle 11g has some tools to track the SQL Statement sending to Oracle?

Like SQL Server profiler trace...

Thanks

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWR reports and Statspack Reports to find the queries submitted to Oracle during certain period of time.

Also, you can use below query for real time monitoring:

```
  SELECT s.SID, s.STATUS, s.process, s.osuser, a.sql_text, p.program
  FROM v$session s, v$sqlarea a, v$process p
  WHERE s.PREV_HASH_VALUE = a.hash_value
   AND s.PREV_SQL_ADDR = a.address
   AND s.paddr = p.addr
   AND s.STATUS = 'ACTIVE';
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Note that AWR reports require an Enterprise Edition with the additional performance pack.

Comment: You can also use STATSPACK as well